# Weights of certain features varying with levels of a feature in model

Tags: logistic, modeling, feature-engineering

I am working on a project where I have to train a model to identify if a trade is considered large based on certain features. I have a large amount of data labeled with 1's (for large) and 0's (for not large). I figured I'd run a logistic regression for this model, but I was told by the end users that the amount of weight they considered for the other features was based on the absolute size of the trade in USD (which is one of the features I used).

E.g. for a trade of size USD 10,000, they would heavily consider the other features of the trade, but for a trade of size USD 5 million, they may not consider the other features at all. I confirmed that the amount of weight the users put on the other features is a strictly negative relationship with the absolute size of the trade.

With this information, I'm not sure how I could use logistic regression besides running it separately for different buckets of trade size. I am also not aware of other modeling approaches that could address this. Has anyone encountered situations like this before? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Try linear or nonlinear splines on the trade size variable. Currently the large trades are killing the significance on other variables, so you could try log(tradeSz). You could apply GAM on the logistic regression, and let the algorithm choose the right knot points.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What exactly would the spline tell? Also, what's GAM?